# python3 checkers board won't print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a checkers game in python but cannot get my board to print to the command line. There are no errors when i run this but nothing happens. I am using python 3 and editing in Vim, My OS is ubuntu. I'm completely lost here so any help would be appreciated.

```
def main():
     print("Python Checkers")
     value_package = dict([("board", init_board()), ("turn_count", 1), 
    ("cur_turn", PLAYERS.White)])
    while True:
        print_board(board)

def init_board():
    board=[
        ['w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_'],
        ['_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w'],
        ['w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_', 'w', '_'],
        ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
        ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
        ['_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b'],
        ['b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_'],
        ['_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b', '_', 'b']]
return board

def print_board(board):
    print("        A B C D E F G H I J\n")
    for i in range (GRID_HEIGHT):
        print(i,  "  |", end="")
         for j in range(GRID_WIDTH):
            print(board[i][j]  + "|", end="")
         print("")
    print("")
```

Comment: *but nothing happens* What is your expected output, and what do you see instead?

Comment: You're not calling any function in your script. Did you forgot to do something like `main()` or `if  __name__ == '__main__': main()`

Comment: call your function main() on the end of this code

Comment: Besides, your indentation is at some places completely wrong, and there are missing definitions for `PLAYERS`, `GRID_HEIGHT` and `GRID_WIDTH`, as well as your `print_board(board)` call needs to be changed to `print_board(value_package["board"])`.

Comment: My expect out put is the game board and i get "Press Enter or type command to continue

Comment: when i call my main function at the bottom of my code i just get a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the entirety of the code?  If so, the program isn't calling main().  Put this at the end of the code to have python run main() as the first function.

Comment: i have another function allowing pieces to jump other pieces but i haven't tried any of it yet as the board won't print